# DB2 data modelling in SQL Developer

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm able to connect to DB2 database on SQL Developer.
 But my question here is how to do the data modelling on SQL Developer for DB2 database.

Thanks,
Anurag

Answer (score 0):

The same as you would do for Oracle or SQL Server.

Build your logical model - entities with attributes and relations.

Forward engineer to a relational model - making sure to set your Model Properties to the RDBMS Type of 'DB2...something'

[image]

Then when generating DDL, you should see IBM DB2 supported syntax.

Note that the ability to do a compare of your model to a database AND generating the ALTER DDL scripts isn't supported for DB2 or SQL Server - only Oracle. You can do the compares, but not the resulting delta DDLs.